# Shell command from c++ code

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, user-interface

I want to create a `GUI` for my linux script. I used `tk` before but I didn't like the `GUI` quality. That's why I am going to use `OpenGL` to create a `GUI` lib that I can extend with time.
My question is how can I run shell commands from the OpenGL C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

- [`system()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) (standard C)
- [`popen()` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (POSIX)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

const std::string exec(const std::string& cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result;
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
    if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```